# Как убрать из MenuItem иконку и пространство справа?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, wpf-шаблоны

Пытаюсь в Menu у `MenuItem`'ов переопределить шаблон, чтобы не было области для иконок и области для отображения сочетаний клавиш. Но после добавления элементов в `DataTemplate`, подпункт меню вообще исчезает.

`XAML`:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0, 0, 0, 3" Height="18" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White">
            <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <MenuItem Header="Файл">
                <MenuItem Header="Создать" Background="White"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Открыть" Background="White"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Выход" Background="White"
                          Command="{Binding CloseApp}"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Справка">
                <!--<MenuItem Header="О программе &quot;Угадай себя&quot;" Command="{Binding OpenAboutUs}"/>-->
                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button Content="О программе &quot;Угадай себя&quot;" Command="{Binding OpenAboutUs}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <!--<Button Content="О программе &quot;Угадай себя&quot;" Command="{Binding OpenAboutUs}"/>-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

Comment: В дизайнере нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на `MenuItem` и там будет создать шаблон - на основе копии. Он вам сгенерирует XAML этого компонента, который достаточно просто будет отредактировать так, как вам надо, удалив лишнее.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, спс, именно так и сделал. Суть в том, что не выделялся в дизайнере вложенный `MenuItem` в `MenuItem`. Как-то случайно получается их выделять, не понимаю от чего это зависит?